# Meaning of a quote on "Umgebung" and "Unterricht"

Tags: meaning, translation, german-to-english

I saw the following quote somewhere:

> Den besten Unterricht zieht man aus vollständiger Umgebung.

I understand every word in this sentence, but I don't get the main idea of the whole sentence.

Comment: Me too. Without context it's next to impossible to tell what exactly "Umgebung" is supposed to mean here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the complete section where the Goethe quote comes from:

> »Wo sind denn aber so vollkommene Lehrer zu finden?« – »Die triffst du sehr leicht«, versetzte Montan. – »Wo denn?« sagte Wilhelm mit einigem Unglauben. – »Da, wo die Sache zu Hause ist, die du lernen willst«, versetzte Montan. **»Den besten Unterricht zieht man aus vollständiger Umgebung.** Lernst du nicht fremde Sprachen in den Ländern am besten, wo sie zu Hause sind? Wo nur diese und keine andere weiter dein Ohr berührt?« <sup>[J .W. v. Goethe: Wilhelm Meisters Wanderjahre](http://gutenberg.spiegel.de/buch/wilhelm-meisters-wanderjahre-3679/6)</sup>

So in this context it will be clear what is meant with this quote. When you want to learn something best you need to learn it in its proper environment. This is elaborated with the example of learning a language best  in the country where it is spoken.